# Can I review which node_modules I need?

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

Is there a way to review which node_modules packages are used in my create-react-app project and delete modules which are not in use? Other than manually reviewing all used packages and their dependencies?

I'd like to reduce the amount of space used up by the project. It's committed to a resources repository, and the node_modules folder alone triples the space used.

Comment: Don't commit node_modules. If you need to store an artifact, store the result of building the app not the source code and all the deps.

Comment: this can be a good starting point: https://gist.github.com/dimkirt/873adea886c4204f74440a2a09d5b2a9 though eventually you'll need to make your own one

Comment: @jonrsharpe in this case it can't be avoided. I'm using an alternative to git and hence don't have access to tools such as gitignore. Given the nature of how the project is used, access to the node_modules is required at this level.

Comment: What VCS *are* you using. How *is* the project used? Without context this seems a lot like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For repo size (assuming you're using git):**

1. `git rm -r --cached ./node_modules`
2. Add the line `/node_modules` to your `.gitignore` file
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "Remove node_modules from repo"`

**For build size:**

`create-react-app` is pretty good at [tree shaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking), so you shouldn't need to worry too much about this. Certain packages may have more modular ways of importing, which can help - usually these will be documented on a package-by-package basis. For example, [Material UI icons](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/#svg-material-icons) supports two `import` syntaxes:

```js
// option 1
import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm'
import ThreeDRotation from '@material-ui/icons/ThreeDRotation'
// option 2
import { AccessAlarm, ThreeDRotation } from '@material-ui/icons'
```

Of these, option 1 is likely to yield the smallest bundle size.

**For size on your development machine:**

The biggest difference you can make here (assuming you have other projects) is probably switching to something like [pnpm](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm), which stores `node_modules` centrally on your local machine and then links out to them from your project, rather than having many instances of identical modules.

**For general housekeeping and tidiness:**

You could try using a tool such as [depcheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck) to detect unused dependencies. This is probably overkill, though, unless it's a particular pain point for your project.

Comment: Thanks, depcheck is exactly what I was after. However it seemed to highlight that all but one of my dependencies are in use. I will probably need to do some further investigation into ways of optimising the code base.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is not to include the node modules by adding it to the gitignore file (or creating one), but if that's not an option, probably just unsintall the unneeded packages